# Gerar Seriais De Verificação Unicos

Tags: php

Alguem sabe como posso fazer um sistema de seriais unico de uma forma que nunca se repita o mesmo serial, ouvi falar que com o rand e o md5 da pra fazer mas não tenho certeza de que uma hora ele não vai se repetir.

Comment: Desde que você armazene a informação, basta fazer sequencial, que não vai ter problema com repetição. Qualquer hash que você adicione vai simplesmente aumentar o risco de colisão. Alternativamente, pode usar algo baseado no tempo atual, desde que tome cuidado com alterações indevidas no relógio da máquina que gera os IDs. ( o UNIQID() do PHP usa o tempo como base)

Comment: Se esse serial for numérico, basta usar um sequencial ou algo parecido com isso que não terá problemas de repetição, conforme o @Bacco já comentou. Caso o Serial precise conter outros caracteres, eu aconselho a usar uuid. Eu uso a classe presente neste link http://br1.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.uniqid.php#94959

Comment: È porque eu não entendi praticamente nada do manual..

Comment: @AlfredoLima aos poucos vc vai pegando o jeito. O importante é entender as vantagens de cada solução e aplicar a que mais te atende bem. Jà tem dois pontos de partida aqui. De qualquer forma, as soluções apresentadas sao melhores que MD5

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você pode gerar um `hash`  "único" assim:

```
$serial = hash('sha512', mt_rand());
echo $serial;
```

**Saida:**

```
8011e6c104db93aeba14974ea471d592c7b3662d52e249be89e5bf978bd8bdf039613cfeb3e11dc9b962f2e953bf16ca56bc675d95dd67796413291f04174af4
```

Se você fizer um `strlen($serial)` verá que serão gerados 128 caracteres aleatórios, a chance de  você conseguir repetir esses caracteres são de `2  bilhões` computados pela função `mt_rand()` que vai de 0 a  2147483647.

Answer (score 4):

Chamar a função sem nenhum parâmetro irá gerar um ID único de 13 caracteres.

Eu utilizei este código e obtive os seguintes resultados:

```
<?php

for ($i = 0; $i < 20; $i++)
{
    echo uniqid() , '<br />';
}
```

Resposta:

```
4e7a2a9eda4f4
4e7a2a9eda513
4e7a2a9eda520
4e7a2a9eda52c
4e7a2a9eda538
4e7a2a9eda53e
4e7a2a9eda545
4e7a2a9eda54a
4e7a2a9eda54f
4e7a2a9eda553
4e7a2a9eda558
4e7a2a9eda55d
4e7a2a9eda562
4e7a2a9eda567
4e7a2a9eda56c
4e7a2a9eda571
4e7a2a9eda576
4e7a2a9eda57b
4e7a2a9eda580
4e7a2a9eda585
```

Fonte e mais exemplos: http://www.phpit.com.br/artigos/gerando-numeros-de-identificacao-id-unicos-com-php.phpit

Comment: Não que a outra resposta seja ruim, mas eu realmente acho mais técnica a sua, pois como comentei, o uniqid() é temporal, e não repete quando usado em condiçoes normais.

Comment: @Bacco concordo existem varias formas de fazer

Answer (score 3):

Normalmente prefiro algo simples usando o timestamp

```
<?php
// retorna 10 caracters numéricos:
// exemplo: 1446815555
echo time();
```

**A chances de colisão**

1. Pode ocorrer quando o ambiente estiver com data errada, no passado, onde em algum ponto pode coincidir com algum timestamp passado já usado. E mesmo nessa situação são chances muito pequenas.
2. Se usado num laço de repetição em execuções muito rápidas, a chance de colisão é muito grande, pois um laço de repetição pode chamar a função `time()` mais de uma vez sob o mesmo milisegundo.

Para esse caso, de uso dentro de um laço de repetição, pode-se evitar colisões incrementando um contador

Exemplo:

```
for ($i = 0; $i<5; $++)
    echo time().$i.PHP_EOL;
```

Imprimirá algo como

```
14468155550
14468155551
14468155552
14468155553
14468155554
```

**Qual estilo ou técnica escolher**

A escolha do tipo de serial depende do modelo de negócios.

Como exemplo, se o serial for usado comercialmente, para suporte a clientes, por exemplo, é inviável apresentar ao cliente um serial desse tipo `8011e6c104db93aeba14974ea471d592c7b3662d52e249be89e5bf978bd8bdf039613cfeb3e11dc9b962f2e953bf16ca56bc675d95dd67796413291f04174af4`

Imagine o atendimento pedindo ao cliente para soletrar o número serial no telefone. rsrs

Por fim, não existe o que é melhor ou pior. Existe o que é mais adequado ou menos adequado para o modelo de negócio.

Porém, em quase todos os casos, quanto menor o serial, melhor. Dentre os requisitos de ser único e ter baixa ou nenhuma possbilidade de colisão.

**Ciclo de vida do Timestamp**

Caso utilize timestamp, esteja atento ao final do ciclo de vida.

O timestamp tem limite até 2038 e isso não está muito longe.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Year_2038_problem