# É possível gerar 2 sequências iguais com md5 se for utilizada a mesma base?

Tags: php, md5

Estava criando um projeto com multiplos upload de imagens e queria que todas ficassem juntas, apenas separadas por "," ex: imagem.jpg,imagem2.jpg...

```
$imagens_name = "";
processo de renomear.. Ele gerava um novo nome com md5 date()
```

no entanto as vezes funcionava envia 2 imagens separadas por , com nome diferente, mas outras vezes enviava a mesma imagem com o mesmo nome, e quando inseria mais de 2 imagens ele gerava as duas primeiras iguais e a 3 diferente. Então troquei o md5 date por "system('date +%s%N');" e agora esta funcionando normalmente.

Minha dúvida é se o script acabava gerando a mesma sequências em 2 imagens pois a date era a mesma (já que quando mudei para microtime ele funcionou), ou se é impossível gerar duas sequências iguais com md5 mesmo que a base (date) seja a mesma ?

Comment: O md5 é "estático" e é por isso que ele existe. Se H(x) = y, se o mesmo `x` for inserido será sempre `y`, logo "duas datas iguais" vão ter exatamente a mesma hash final. Portanto não é só "possível" como é o comportamento normal e esperado dele, isso permite verificar integridade básica e é somente para isto que ele serve.

Comment: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/170920/gerando-identificador-%C3%BAnico-utilizando-time

Comment: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/96520/gerar-seriais-de-verifica%C3%A7%C3%A3o-unicos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A string MD5 será sempre a mesma para uma mesma string base.

Exemplo: 

`1` -> `c4ca4238a0b923820dcc509a6f75849b`

`abc` -> `900150983cd24fb0d6963f7d28e17f72`

Conforme descreveu na pergunta, a lógica estava inconsistente pois usar a data corrente pode implicar em conflito de nomes duplicados pois um laço de repetição normalmente executa os processos em milisegundos.

A função `microtime()` também pode retornar um mesmo valor dentro desse contexto pois se a iteração for muito rápida, pode retornar valor igual a um valor anterior.

É mais consistente garantir valores únicos concatenando algo mais seguro.

```
for($n = 1; $n < 10; $n++) {
    echo date('YmdHis').PHP_EOL;
}

//resultado:
20170518061514
20170518061514
20170518061514
20170518061514
20170518061514
20170518061514
20170518061514
20170518061514
20170518061514
```

Isso é como tentou fazer. Observe que 10 iterações foram executadas em menos de 1 segundo, por isso os valores se repetem.

Uma ideia para tornar cada valor único é adicionar algum identificador único.

```
/*
Nesse exemplo é concatenado o número da iteração corrente.
*/
for($n = 1; $n < 10; $n++) {
    echo date('YmdHis').':'.$n.PHP_EOL;
}

/*
Resultado
*/

20170518061756:1
20170518061756:2
20170518061756:3
20170518061756:4
20170518061756:5
20170518061756:6
20170518061756:7
20170518061756:8
20170518061756:9
```

Veja como fica implementando com MD5:

```
for($n = 1; $n < 10; $n++) {
    echo md5(date('YmdHis').':'.$n).PHP_EOL;
}

475531f945b1fe26a4849ab4f5474fd7
4e0fc04b52d05a86688892dd0ad92552
a58d7865693971aec8f6867de725dc0a
7f9d7c97091b11024295eed5641c99de
2e826491e8b9da0a005777f78ba9550b
ff8ab9eb829a36de0410bb9773a6315e
52e0220c76d2a18a210bfadb29158c39
659ec7a31ae61abd7022b6e21fb008e2
88da547523beb6d5f4f7c2a6aaa79037
```

Claro, deve estar ciente de que o MD5 pode produzir colisões mesmo com strings diferentes. Mas isso é algo dificilmente ou quase que impossível para a finalidade do contexto da pergunta.

Para garantir maior integridade, grave os dados sem encriptar. Ocupará menos espaço e fica livre de colisões mesmo que sejam raras para esse caso.

Caso seja importante não gravar o formato numérico das datas, pode mascarar com "short id". São IDs curtas tipo as do Youtube ou serviços de encurtamento de URL. Mas isso fica fora do foco da pergunta.